# tkinter countdown app stop and reset button not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a first attempt at a tkinter countdown app and I'm struggling with the stop and reset buttons as well as parts of the interface design.

My stop button does nothing at all whereas my reset button resets the values, but then continues the countdown immediately. I suspect it's because I have set `self.running` to `True` in the init method and that my app loops through those lines again and again. How do I prevent that from happening?

The other issue is that my width argument in all of my entry fields gets seemingly ignored. How can I assign the same width to all three fields?

Thanks for your help.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import messagebox

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.place()
        self.widgets()
        self.running = True

    def widgets(self):

        self.hour = StringVar()
        self.hour.set("00")
        # Why is the width ignored?
        self.hour_entry = Entry(width = 7, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.hour)
        self.hour_entry.place(x = 10, y = 10)

        self.minute = StringVar()
        self.minute.set("00")
        self.minute_entry = Entry(width = 7, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.minute)
        self.minute_entry.place(x = 30, y = 10)

        self.second = StringVar()
        self.second.set("00")
        self.seconds_entry = Entry(width = 7, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.second)
        self.seconds_entry.place(x = 50, y = 10)

        self.start_btn = Button(text = "Start", command=self.clock)
        self.start_btn.place(x = 30, y = 100)

        self.stop_btn = Button(text = "Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stop_btn.place(x = 70, y = 100)

        self.reset_btn = Button(text = "Reset", command=self.reset)
        self.reset_btn.place(x = 110, y = 100)

    def clock(self):

        if self.running == True:

            self.time_total = int(self.hour_entry.get())*3600 + int(self.minute_entry.get())*60 + int(self.seconds_entry.get())

            while self.time_total > -1:

                # returns 3600/60 = 60 with 0 left: so that's 60 min, 0 seconds
                self.mins, self.secs = divmod(self.time_total,60) 

                self.hours = 0
                if self.mins > 60:
                    
                    self.hours, self.mins = divmod(self.mins, 60)

                self.hour.set("{0:02d}".format(self.hours))
                self.minute.set("{0:02d}".format(self.mins))
                self.second.set("{0:02d}".format(self.secs))

                self.time_total -= 1
                root.update()
                time.sleep(1)

                if self.time_total == 0:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up!")
    
    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.clock()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def reset(self):
        self.running = False
        self.hour.set("00")
        self.minute.set("00")
        self.second.set("00")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the timer, use the `after` method instead of `sleep`.

The entry widths are being used, but the `place` method puts one entry on top of another.

Also - Call the `start` method from the button click to reset the `running` flag.

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import messagebox

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.place()
        self.widgets()
        self.running = False

    def widgets(self):
        self.hour = StringVar()
        self.hour.set("00")
        # Why is the width ignored?
        self.hour_entry = Entry(width = 4, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.hour)
        self.hour_entry.place(x = 10, y = 10)

        self.minute = StringVar()
        self.minute.set("00")
        self.minute_entry = Entry(width = 4, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.minute)
        self.minute_entry.place(x = 60, y = 10)

        self.second = StringVar()
        self.second.set("00")
        self.seconds_entry = Entry(width = 4, font=("Calibri",14,""), textvariable = self.second)
        self.seconds_entry.place(x = 110, y = 10)

        self.start_btn = Button(text = "Start", command=self.start)
        self.start_btn.place(x = 30, y = 100)

        self.stop_btn = Button(text = "Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stop_btn.place(x = 70, y = 100)

        self.reset_btn = Button(text = "Reset", command=self.reset)
        self.reset_btn.place(x = 110, y = 100)

    def clock(self):
        if self.running == True:
            
            # returns 3600/60 = 60 with 0 left: so that's 60 min, 0 seconds
            self.mins, self.secs = divmod(self.time_total,60) 

            self.hours = 0
            if self.mins > 60:
                self.hours, self.mins = divmod(self.mins, 60)

            self.hour.set("{0:02d}".format(self.hours))
            self.minute.set("{0:02d}".format(self.mins))
            self.second.set("{0:02d}".format(self.secs))

            root.update()
            #time.sleep(1)
            root.after(1000, self.clock)  # wait 1 second, re-call clock

            if self.time_total == 0:
                self.running = False
                messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up!")
            self.time_total -= 1
                    
    
    def start(self):
        self.time_total = int(self.hour_entry.get())*3600 + int(self.minute_entry.get())*60 + int(self.seconds_entry.get())
        self.running = True
        self.clock()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def reset(self):
        self.running = False
        self.hour.set("00")
        self.minute.set("00")
        self.second.set("00")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Definitely learned something about `after` and `place`.